# multithreaded web application in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

I am doing a web application which has Java as a front end and shell script as a back end. The concept is I need to process multiple files in the back end. I will get the date range from the user (for example from July 1st-8th) and for each day process around 100 files. So in total I have 800 files to process.

I will get these details from JSP and delegate a background call to shell script and get back the results and display the same to the user.

Now I did all these in a sequential approach - by which I mean without threads. So there is only one main thread that executes and the user has to wait till 800 files are processed sequentially. However this is really slow. And because of this I am thinking of going for threads. Since I am a beginner of threads, I read a some stuffs regarding this and I have come up with the following idea:

> As I read threads work have to be split .. I thought of splitting the
>   8 day work to 4 threads where each thread would perform 2 day work

I would like to know whether I am following a correct approach and my major concerns are:

1. Is it recommended to spawn multiple threads from a web application
2. Whether or not this is a good approach

Some guidance of how to proceed with this. An example instance would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run the long processing job in multi-threaded or in any high performance environment. You should also you Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Request Processing to suspend the request thread and wait till the Long processing task is done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there's nothing wrong with spawning multiple threads from a web application.  In fact, if you're running a Servlet container (which you most likely are since you're using Java), it's already spawning multiple threads for you.  In general a Servlet container will automatically spawn a new thread (or reuse one out of a pool) to handle each request it receives.
2. Your approach is fine, thought you'll want to fine-tune the number of threads to something that is suitable given the hardware configuration of your system and the amount of concurrent load on your web service.  Also note that while spinning up a bunch of threads will reduce the total amount of time needed to process all the data, it will still leave a potentially large chunk of time before any data is ready to go back to the user.  So you might get a better result by doing smaller work units sequentially, and posting each batch of results to the user-interface as soon as it is ready.  Then it will still take a long while for the user to have all the data, but that can start viewing at least a portion of it almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Create threads in a web application is not a good solution. It is a bad design because normally it would be the container (web server) who is charged with that activity. So I think you have to find another solution.

I suggest you putting the shell scripts in cron, scheduled to run each minute, and to "activate" them you can touch files that act as semaphores. At each run the scripts verify if the web application touched the semaphore file, if so they read the date interval from those files and then start to process.

Answer (score 0):

The way to improve user experience is not by parallelizing at Servlet level on 100000 threads but rather to provide incremental rendering of the view. First of all it would be useful to separate your application in multiple layers, according to the MVC pattern for example.

Saying that, you will have to look on how

- Create a service that is able to return partial answers and a last answer, meaning that all available data has been returned. Each of this answers can be computed in parallel to improve performance.
- Fill a web page incrementally, tipically by calling back this service which returns a JSON string you use to add data to the DOM. Every time you get an answer, if this is a partial answer, you call again the service providing the previous sequence number.

If you look to Liligo to understand, you will see how this is works. The technique I described is known as polling, but there are others technique to obtain similar asynchronous results at UI Level. In general, you don't want to work directly with the Servlet API, which is a very low level API,but rather use a reasonable framework or abstraction for that.

If you want a warm advice, you should have a look to the Play! framework http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaStream HTTP streaming.